# How to trigger submit from parent?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I would like to call the submit method of the child component. Therefore I use the ref prop. 
But it looks like I just get a WithContext object.

So how to call `TodoForm > submit` inside `App > submitForm`.

Here is a running example: https://codesandbox.io/s/92nm15pnqr

Comment: from App.js pass `onSubmit={this.submitForm} ` and from TodoForm in `Formik` onSubmit add `this.props.onSubmit()`

Comment: The submit button is outside of the TodoForm. Thus, submit should be triggered outside of the TodoForm.Therefore onSubmit prop for TodoForm will not help.

Comment: why do you put submit button outside?

Comment: For example bootstrap modal where submit button is in the modal footer and the form itself is in the modal body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wrap your `TodoForm` component in `withNamespaces` HOC, getting the reference to your `TodoForm` is not as easy as calling `ref={..}`, since that returns reference to the HOC. To get the reference to your component, you have to leverage the `innerRef` parameter, when creating the HOC (see [docs](https://react.i18next.com/components/withnamespaces))

```
const TodoFormTranslated = withNamespaces("", {
  innerRef: (ref) => VARIABLE_WHICH_WILL_NOW_CONTAIN_REF_TO_YOUR_EL = ref
})(TodoForm);
```

fast but working solution to your problem would look something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/n55yvw1o2m

Maybe you don't want variables outside of your class, so I'll leave that to you in which way do you want to handle this. You can get inspiration for example from [this post](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/599#issuecomment-435608037).

Comment: have this helped solving your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was able to access the method in child component but I had no access to formik specific props like submitForm. So I decided to solve this issue with an additional props in TodoForm to trigger the form submit. This has the disadvantage that I need to write additional code but I see no other way.

Comment: but you were able to run the `submit` method of the TodoForm then right? that what the question stated. You can post another question for the next issue.

Comment: OK, from that perspective the problem is solved. :-)